# need to create circle around coordinate using JTS library

Tags: java, jts

i am trying to create circle around specific coordinate using below method which I got from some git hub repo.

```
public static Geometry createCircle(Coordinate coordinate, double radius)
{
  GeometricShapeFactory shape = new GeometricShapeFactory(geomFactory);
  shape.setCentre(coordinate);
  shape.setSize(2 * radius);
  shape.setNumPoints(32);
  return shape.createCircle();
}
```

I want to pass the radius in miles, but looks like its taking in some other unit and the circle getting created is huge when I am giving 5 as radius. Can someone explain how can I use radius argument in miles in above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JTS is geometry/topology library.  As such, it uses whatever units the geometry is in.

Assuming you are working with a point that is a longitude, latitude pair, then the units are degrees of longitude/latitude.  At the equator, a degree is around ~110 kilometers / 69 miles.

As a really quick fix, you could set your radius to something like 5/69.  As a complete solution, you could apply GeoTools's (a Java geospatial library) GeodeticCalculator class [1] to the code you suggested to get a more accurate circle.

That solution will have some issues around the poles, but that's another issue...

[1] http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/calculator.html

Comment: when I passed shape.setSize(1);  to check the actual distance between source and destination I got below result: 

source = -84.529793, 33.961886 & destination = -84.03940035979838 34.059431161008064 (from above formula)

distance is aproximately 29mi . As per you 1/69 degree = 1 mile radius, can you please help me understand this.

Comment: Sure.  A degree of latitude is always the same when converted to meters/miles/etc.  Degrees of longitude shrink as they move closer to the poles.

At 33 degrees off the equator, a degree of longitude is around 58 miles (per this campy, yet handy web calculator: http://www.csgnetwork.com/degreelenllavcalc.html).

My guess is .setSize is setting the diameter.

Comment: 1/29 ~ 1 mile (approximately ) so your response "33 degrees off the equator, a degree of longitude is around 58 miles" really helped. Thanks a lot